# Is it possible to use https on a WCF (desktop) service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF (desktop) service providing a Rest API very similar to the one that Microsft shows in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service

Is it possible to use https on a WCF (desktop) service?

I've found a lot of examples using Asp and IIS, but as this is not a webapp I don't know whether it could be done or not.

Comment: Yes you can, there is HTTPS binding for WCF

Comment: Do you have any example/link I can have a look on?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?, i think you can host a web api in windows services too

Comment: keep in mind that only dot net 4.8 support WCF, dot net 5 and future dot nets will not support WCF. Microsoft has ended support for WCF.

Comment: I would like to encrypt/secure the data retrieved by the Rest API, that's why I want to use HTTPS. I'm afraid that data might be exposed.

Comment: Hope these links can help you.[Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https) and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi